# Concurrency and Thread Pools

Tags: concurrency, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

If you want to have a thread pool with only 10 threads, which of the following techniques is best to achieve this purpose?

1. Invoke the newCachedThreadPool() method of the java.util.concurrent.Executors class by passing 10 as the parameter.
2. Invoke the newCachedThreadPool() method of the java.util.concurrent.Executor class by passing 10 as the parameter.
3. Invoke the newFixedThreadPool() method of the java.util.concurrent.Executors class by passing 10 as the parameter.
4. Invoke the newFixedThreadPool() method of the java.util.concurrent.Executor class by passing 10 as the parameter.
5. FixedThreadPool fx = new FixedThreadPool(10);

Answer (score 0):

Of the 5 things you have listed, only the 3rd actually [exists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-). So I would suggest using that.